# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) with axios.put and using props in vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-props

I have tried to use props to pass data across components but I have problem with select option, how can I put the value is `role.id` into `updateUser()` function using `axios.put` without error 422

[image]

**Modals.vue**

```
    <div class="modal modal-black fade" id="userEditModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">
                Edit user
                 <strong class="text-primary">{{ name }} - {{ username }}</strong>
              </h4>
              <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="tim-icons icon-simple-remove"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
    
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="username"
                        v-model.lazy="username" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="username"
                        v-model.lazy="name" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        v-model.lazy="email" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Roles</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select v-model="roleSelected" name="roles">
                        <option
                          v-for="role in roles"
                          :key="role.index"
                          :value="role.id">
                          {{ role.name }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer d-flex flex-row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                 Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="updateBtn()">
                 Save
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "Modals",
      props: ["name", "username", "email", "roles"],
      data() {
        return {
          roleSelected: "",
        };
      },
      emits: ["trigger"],
      methods: {
        updateBtn() {
          this.$emit("trigger", "");
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**ManageUsers**

```
<Modals
        :name="userInfo.name"
        :username="userInfo.username"
        :email="userInfo.email"
        :roles="roles"
        @trigger="updateUser()"
      />
    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import Modals from "/src/components/cores/Modals.vue";
    export default {
      name: "manageUsers",
      components: { Modals },
      data() {
        return {
          users: [],
          roles: [],
          hidden: false,
          index: 0,
          newUser: {
            name: null,
            username: null,
            email: null,
            password: null,
            confirmPassword: null,
            roles: null,
          },
          userInfo: {
            uuid: "",
            name: "",
            username: "",
            phone: "",
            email: "",
            role: "",
          },
        };
      },
      methods: {
        
        getRoles() {
          axios.get(`/roles/listRoles`).then((res) => {
            this.roles = res.data.data;
          });
        },
        refreshUsers() {
          axios.get(`/users/allusers`).then((res) => {
            this.users = res.data.data;
          });
        },
        addUser() {
          axios
            .post(`/users/create`, this.newUser);
        },
    
        getUserInfo(user) {
          axios
            .get(`/users/show/${user.uuid}`)
            .then((res) => {
              this.userInfo.uuid = res.data.data.uuid;
              this.userInfo.name = res.data.data.name;
              this.userInfo.email = res.data.data.email;
              this.userInfo.username = res.data.data.username;
              this.userInfo.phone = res.data.data.phone;
            });
        },
    
        updateUser() {
          axios
            .put(`/users/update/${this.userInfo.uuid}`, {
              name: this.userInfo.name,
              username: this.userInfo.username,
              email: this.userInfo.email,
              roles: this.roleSelected,
            })
            .then((res) => {
              this.refreshUsers();
            })
        },
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getRoles();
        this.refreshUsers();
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**Roles list data**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Master",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Manager",
        },
    ]
}
```

**User Info**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "uuid": "5ebc3892-49b7-4468-81e4-aaf1742d3dff",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "username": "johnjohn",
    },
}
```

Comment: Data inside put request can not be handled by backend, so check the backend what it is expecting.

Comment: your method `updateBtn()`  does not send the `roleSelected` date in the emit, you should probably do something like this `this.$emit("trigger", roleSelected);` to retrieve the correct value in your ManageUsers component with `updateUser(roleSelected) {`